# How can I keep variable values specific for each individual connected clients in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Nodejs and using Visual Studio 2015 with Basic Nodejs Express 4 app template.

Setting some values through a post request from client. Then I open another tab and send another post request. The values I set on previous request persists. I would like to set variables for each connected clients.

Nodejs Code

```
var someValue = 0;
app.post('/set-values', function (req, res, next) {
    var reqBody = req.body;
    someValue += parseInt(reqBody.someValue);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ value:someValue }));
});
```

Client Code

```
$.post("http://localhost:1337" + "/set-values", { someValue: 5 }, function     (d) {
    var data = JSON.parse(d);
    console.log(data.value);
});
```

When the client makes request, console value is 5 then on another request it is 10 then on another it is 15... 
I would like to have 5 for all requests and keep someValue property 0 when each connection starts but i also need it outside of the post scope. Every search send me pages about socket.io client or user  authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a key for identity request.

If we assuming you will do this on client-side, your code should be like below:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var val = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    localStorage.setItem("key", val);
} else {
   alert("web storage not supported")
}


$.post("http://localhost:1337" + "/set-values", { someValue: 5, key:localStorage.getItem("key") }, function(d) {
    var data = JSON.parse(d);
    console.log(data.value);
});
```

And your server-side:

```
var dataStore = [];

app.post('/set-values', function (req, res,next) {
   if(dataStore[req.body.key] == undefined) dataStore[req.body.key] = 0;
   dataStore[req.body.key] += parseInt(req.body.someValue);
   res.send(JSON.stringify({ value:dataStore[req.body.key] }));
})
```

In this case we used HTML5 LocalStorage, You can try jQuery Cookie or another something.

Comment: I have been avoiding this logic and looking for an identity solution on server side. It's been a surprise to see that all clients connect same app instance. I guess node does not work like asp or php.

Comment: Any suggestion how to clean dataStore on node side?